# How do i connect bridges in simcity?

Tags: simcity-2013

I was wondering if there is any way to connect bridges with each other in the simcity game? If yes then how would I do it?

Comment: Have you ever seen this done in real life to a large scale?

Answer (score 2):

No.  You cannot create an intersection on a bridge.  You must connect the bridge to the ground and have the intersection on the ground.  From that intersection, you can create another bridge.